# Unable to retrieve message body on server-side from HTTP Post

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am sending an HTTP post request using HTTPWebRequest to an URL. I am sending the post data using multipart/form-data content type along with the content length of the body. However, on the server side, I am unable to retrieve the body. I can only see the headers sent. The content length of the body I sent also matches.

Why am I not able to retrieve the body.

The request method looks like this:

```
public void Reset(string originalFileData, string uploadLocation)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Server), portNo);
        client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
        string responseContent;
        string serverUrl = "http://" + Server + ":" + portNo + "/abc.aspx" + "?uplvar=" + uploadLocation;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUrl);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        string postData = originalFileData;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Edit: I forgot to mention, I am able to retrieve the body on the first time I send the request, but on any subsequent requests I send, I am not able to retrieve it. I am creating a new connection each time I send a request. So, something might be preventing the request body from being retrieved. I am not sure why.

Comment: Note: Your TcpClient code at the beginning has no relevance to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
```

with

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

or check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) for code which works with multipart/formdata.

Comment: I tried that approach. It didn't work. I made an edit to the original question at the end. That might help clarifying further. Thanks.

Comment: Then I would fire up Fiddler and see what goes over the wire for the first and second request, and compare them.